# Class 'AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>' has no instance getter 'docs'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i'm chargin data from firestore and i have this, I'm new in firestore and I don't know so much, so ¿Can you help me?

```dart
Container(
  height: 700,
  child: GridView.builder(
    itemCount: snapShot.data.docs.length,
    // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => SingleProduct(
        name: snapShot.docs.data[index]["name"],
        price: snapShot.docs.data[index]["precio"],
        image: snapShot.docs.data[index]["image"]),
    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: 0.7,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10),
  ),
)
```

And the error is this: Class 'AsyncSnapshot' has no instance getter 'docs'.
Receiver: Instance of 'AsyncSnapshot'
Tried calling: docs

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are mistaken one snapshot with the other.

You have an instance of [`AsyncSnapshot`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot-class.html) in your `snapShot` variable. This snapshot might be in a loading state or **contain the snapshot you are looking for**.

You can check if it already has data like this:

```dart
final querySnapshot = snapshot.data;
if (querySnapshot == null) return Container();

// Now, you are safe to use your querySnapshot.
querySnapshot.docs
// ...
```

---

The error in your code are the following lines:

```dart
itemBuilder: (context, index) => SingleProduct(
                    name: snapShot.docs.data[index]["name"],
                    price: snapShot.docs.data[index]["precio"],
                    image: snapShot.docs.data[index]["image"]),
```

Here you are trying to access `snapShot.docs` instead of the correct `snapShot.data.docs`.